# Alexa AudioPlayer is not started, but no error is thrown

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to start a radio stream on Alexa by using the AudioPlayer.
The user should be able to select one of two local radio stations by using a slot. That part is working.

When the intent is launched, the code doesn't throw any error. However the radio stream is not started (even not on my local Dot).

It seems to me that the code is still waiting for something, but I can't figure out what is missing.

```
CompletedLocalRadioIntentHandler : {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && request.intent.name === 'LocalRadioIntent'
            && request.dialogState === 'COMPLETED';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
        //const filledSlots = request.intent.slots;
        //const slotValues = getSlotValues(filledSlots);
        //const key = `${slotValues.RadioStation.key}`;
        // const radioURL = `${slotsToOptionsMap[key]}`;
        const radioUrl = 'https://wdr-1live-live.sslcast.addradio.de/wdr/1live/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .addDirective({
                shouldEndSession: true,
                type: 'AudioPlayer.Play',
                playBehavior: 'REPLACE_ALL',
                audioItem: {
                    stream: {
                       token: "0",
                        url: radioUrl,
                        expectedPreviousToken: null,
                        offsetInMilliseconds: 0
                    },
                }
            })
    },
}
```

Comment: Try getting rid of 'shouldEndSession: true'

Comment: I've added it because it didn't work either before. So leaving it or deleting it, doesn't matter. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The common issues with audioplayer interfaces is the strict audio requirements, this looks the reason of your issue. The link provided by Amod is for the SSML not audioplayer. Make sure to follow all the requirements for audio stream:

```
-Audio file must be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint on port 443.
-The web server must present a valid and trusted SSL certificate. Self-signed certificates are not allowed (really important).Many content hosting services provide this. For example, you could host your files at a service such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) (an Amazon Web Services offering).
-If the stream is a playlist container that references additional streams, each stream within the playlist must also be hosted at an Internet-accessible HTTPS endpoint on 443 with a valid and trusted SSL certificate.
-The supported formats for the audio file include AAC/MP4, MP3, PLS, M3U/M3U8, and HLS. Bitrates: 16kbps to 384 kbps.
```

This information can be found on the official documentation below: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#audio-stream-requirements

There is an AudioPlayer sample skill which actually streams from a radio station already to which you can refer. That can be found here: https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player

You will need to change the url stream and add your own.